# What could have happened to Jane's library card that would make her have to borrow someone else's card?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> What could have happened to Jane's library card that would make her have to borrow someone else's card?

What's the antecedent of 'that'? Jane's library card or 'What ~ card"?

Comment: source of the quote pls

Comment: Her _card_ didn't cause her to borrow someone else's, did it?

Comment: @KateBunting 'did' cause her to borrow someone else's card because her card expired.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Obviously it was _the fact that something had happened to her [own] card_ that caused her to borrow another.

Comment: @KateBunting You think the antecedent is 'card' in my example?

Comment: I was trying to help  you to work out for yourself that **What could have happened to Jane's library card?** is the antecedent of **that**!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [What could have happened to Jane's library card] that would make her have to borrow someone else's card?

We work backward by answering the bracketed question.

Card expiry, loss, and damage are possibilities.  Hence we could say

> **Card expiry** would make her have to borrow someone else's card.

but not

> **Jane's library card* would make her have to borrow someone else's card.

The antecedent of *that* is hence *What could have happened to Jane's library card*.